# difflib.SequenceMatcher isjunk argument not considered?

Tags: python, difflib, sequencematcher

In the python difflib library, is the SequenceMatcher class behaving unexpectedly, or am I misreading what the supposed behavior is?

Why does the isjunk argument seem to not make any difference in this case?

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "AA", "A A").ratio() return 0.8

difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x in ' ', "AA", "A A").ratio() returns 0.8
```

My understanding is that if space is omitted, the ratio should be 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because the `ratio` function uses total sequences' length while calculating the ratio, **but it doesn't filter elements using `isjunk`**. So, as long as the number of matches in the matching blocks results in the same value (with and without `isjunk`), the ratio measure will be the same.

I assume that sequences are not filtered by `isjunk` because of performance reasons.

```python
def ratio(self):   
    """Return a measure of the sequences' similarity (float in [0,1]).

    Where T is the total number of elements in both sequences, and
    M is the number of matches, this is 2.0*M / T.
    """

    matches = sum(triple[-1] for triple in self.get_matching_blocks())
    return _calculate_ratio(matches, len(self.a) + len(self.b))
```

`self.a` and `self.b` are the strings (sequences) passed to the SequenceMatcher object ("AA" and "A A" in your example). The `isjunk` function `lambda x: x in ' '` is only used to determine the matching blocks. Your example is quite simple, so the resulting ratio and matching blocks are the same for both calls.

```python
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "AA", "A A").get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=1), Match(a=1, b=2, size=1), Match(a=2, b=3, size=0)]

difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == ' ', "AA", "A A").get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=1), Match(a=1, b=2, size=1), Match(a=2, b=3, size=0)]
```

*Same matching blocks, the ratio is*: `M = 2, T = 6 => ratio = 2.0 * 2 / 6`

**Now consider the following example**:

```python
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "AA ", "A A").get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=1, b=0, size=2), Match(a=3, b=3, size=0)]

difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == ' ', "AA ", "A A").get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=1), Match(a=1, b=2, size=1), Match(a=3, b=3, size=0)]
```

*Now matching blocks are different, but the ratio will be the same because the number of matches is still equal*:

*When `isjunk` is None*: `M = 2, T = 6 => ratio = 2.0 * 2 / 6`

*When `isjunk` is* `lambda x: x == ' '`: `M = 1 + 1, T = 6 => ratio = 2.0 * 2 / 6`

**Finally, a different number of matches:**

```python
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, "AA ", "A A ").get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=1, b=0, size=2), Match(a=3, b=4, size=0)]

difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == ' ', "AA ", "A A ").get_matching_blocks()
[Match(a=0, b=0, size=1), Match(a=1, b=2, size=2), Match(a=3, b=4, size=0)]
```

*The number of matches is different*

*When `isjunk` is None*: `M = 2, T = 7 => ratio = 2.0 * 2 / 7`

*When `isjunk` is* `lambda x: x == ' '`: `M = 1 + 2, T = 6 => ratio = 2.0 * 3 / 7`

Comment: How to then match and ignore some simple lines of characters like the one in question's example if isjunk doesn't work that way? More specifically is there a build in function/method to simply ignore some characters when calculating similarity ratio?

Comment: Agreed, it's a strange property to use when it doesn't "do anything" as such

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the characters from the string before sequencing it

```
def withoutJunk(input, chars):
    return input.translate(str.maketrans('', '', chars))

a = withoutJunk('AA', ' ')
b = withoutJunk('A A', ' ')
difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()
# -> 1.0
```