# Python regular expression for strings similarity comparison

Tags: python, regex, string, similarity

I found that `SequenceMatcher` from library `difflib` can return a similarity score between two strings. However one of the argument `isjunk` is little bit tricky to deal with, especially with regular expressions.

Take two strings for example:

```
a = 'Carrot 500g'
b = 'Cabbage 500g'

from difflib import SequenceMatcher
import re

def similar_0(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()

similar_0(a, b)

def similar_1(a, b):
    return SequenceMatcher(lambda x: bool(re.search(r'\b(\d)+([a-zA-Z])+\b', x)), a, b).ratio()

similar_1(a, b)
```

When comparing these two strings, I want to ignore all the unit information like "500g" above. But I got the same result using `similar_0` vs `similar_1`. I'm really confused as to how `isjunk` works in `SequenceMatcher` as an argument. What is the correct way to achieve the purpose, or any other alternatives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129357/difflib-sequencematcher-isjunk-argument-not-considered)

Comment: Having looked at that post, I'm even more confused because my question has something to do with regexp. Appreciate it very much if you could provide a simpler explanation.

Comment: @JamesWong Do you want a regex to remove any weight (500g, 100g, 2kg) from your string? If so, have you got more examples?

Comment: I doubt this question has much to do with regex. It is more about how the string is parsed when passed to SequenceMatcher. The regex itself is great and working - matches `500g`.

Comment: @MrMysteryGuest Exactly, I want to filter out any unit like (500g, 100g, 2kg) as well as (500ml, 1lb) etc. I think the regexp works but the question is how does it work with `SequenceMatcher`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried removing any weight extension before passing them to `SequenceMatcher` - Carrot vs Cabbage? Instead of a = Carrot 500g vs Cabbage 500g

Comment: That didn't even cross my mind actually. And I think @Rawing just suggested that same idea as an answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Your regex doesn't work because `SequenceMatcher` passes individual characters to the `isjunk` function, not words:

```
>>> SequenceMatcher(print, 'Carrot 500g', 'Cabbage 500g')
b
0
5
a
e

g
C
```

You should just remove the junk from both strings *before* passing them to `SequenceMatcher`:

```
a = re.sub(r'\b(\d)+([a-zA-Z])+\b', '', a)
b = re.sub(r'\b(\d)+([a-zA-Z])+\b', '', b)
print(similar_0(a, b))
```

Comment: Oh, great. I didn't know that. I think your solution is decent enough. Thanks.